# Change Date format to (dd-mmm-yy) if the inserted values are Date , Not Work?

Tags: excel, vba

I need Change Date format to **(dd-mmm-yy)** if the inserted values are **Date** ,But it is Not Work !

the current result format is `dd-mm-yy` and the expected is `dd-mmm-yy`.
I tried the below code.  as always,any help will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("E:F")) Is Nothing Then  'Change Date format to dd-mmm-yy
  
        If Not IsDate(Target.value) = False Then
         
         Target.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
         
         End If
       End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to loop, if you're changing multiple cells at once. Note that changing the number format doesn't change the underlying value. If you're working with *text-that-looks-like-a-date*, changing the number format won't do anything. You'd need to convert it to a date first (maybe using `CDate` or `DateValue`).

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Columns("E:F"))

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
   Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In rng
       If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
           cell.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
       End If
   Next
End If
```

Comment: Please, is your code will loop the whole the range Columns("E:F") every time , if date is inserted ?

Comment: No, it will only loop over the cells in `Target` that are in Columns E:F.